# Your recent app submission was rejected for violating the Google Play Developer Programme Policies

Tags: android, google-play-console

(1)  My App simple Education Base Content and test Attempt.
(2)   Not Any  google ads only one you tube integration

This simple App , Login from Activation key given from institute .

Google  Send a mail App reject Im not understand Why

Issue: Violation of Families Policy Requirements
Apps that contain elements that appeal to children must comply with all Families Policy Requirements. We found the following issue(s) with your app:

Eligibility Issue
Test Login Needed
In order to review your app for “Designed for Families” eligibility, we will need you to provide a test login account. Please provide login credentials to the support team before you submit any updated version for another review (select “Test Login Needed” and include the test login account and password details in the open box field).

Comment: I think it's quite clear. "Provide a test login" so that their support team can make sure your application's content is actually designed for families and not for adults

Comment: it's pretty much clear already

Comment: Did you manage to publish your app in the end? We're stuck getting rejected for the exact same reason even though we are providing the Test Login info...

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 3):

> Eligibility Issue Test Login Needed In order to review your app for “Designed for Families” eligibility, we will need you to provide a test login account. Please provide login credentials to the support team before you submit any updated version for another review (select “Test Login Needed” and include the test login account and password details in the open box field).

I think that it is quite self-explanatory. You must contact the support team and provide a test user credentials (email, password) for your app so they can test it.

Comment: Though this does address the issue in the question, how do you actually do this? I have the same issue as OP and we have supplied the test credentials in the Store Presence -> App Content that appears when you select <13 age groups but we _still_ are getting this same rejection response from Google "No Test Login Provided". 

I think an answer needs to address how specifically you provide a test login that satisfies the requirement...

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue but were also still getting rejected (for the same reason) even after providing the test login info, without any further clarifications. We provided the test login info both in Play Console (App Content -> Target audience and content -> Instructions for app access), but also via the web form linked from the rejection email. We also tried resubmitting the app and doing everything from scratch like 5 times total - always the same result. So either we're crazy and our test login credentials aren't working (which we checked many times) or their system is bugging out.

So, what eventually got us published was changing our "Target age group" configuration in Play Console (App Content -> Target audience and content -> Target age group) - we unchecked everything below `13-15`. Not sure if you had those checked, but if you did, try unchecking them then resubmit the app.

I realize that we basically had to lie and are now maybe risking some penalty (getting removed from the Play Store?) but doing everything right got us nowhere, so we had to resort to this "cheating".

Not saying you should do what we did, just saying what worked for us. Do it at your own risk.

Comment: Kindly Note.If you  un check  below 13-15.  you app will not be visible to kids section.In google play it will mentioned the app is not suitable for kids or it applicable only for  18. So if you target users is kids, or less than 12-15.you may loss the audience. so think and act. Mail to google play console  they will reply and continuoulsy mailed them. they will reply .i have faced this problem and managed to published @ end.