# How to fix “Issue:Test login Needed” issue in GooglePlayConsole

Tags: android, google-play

I have submitted app in google play.I got a reply from them  Test Login needed. I have provided test login needed in Target content network. I have updated my app. I have mailed google play support team my username and password. Google Support team said that we have changed  our status.

Once again i have received mail from play store that your update has been rejected because you have not provided test login needed. They said

Apps that contain elements that appeal to children must comply with all Families Policy Requirements. We found the following issue(s) with your app:

In order to review your app for “Designed for Families” eligibility, we will need you to provide a test login account. Please provide login credentials to the support team before you submit any updated version for another review (select “Test Login Needed” and include the test login account and password details in the open box field)."

Many times our has been rejected for same reason even i have provided test login account and forward to them also.

What i have to Do. Did any one have exp on this issue?

[image: Picture]

Comment: Did you manage to get published in the end? If yes, what did you have to do? We are having the exact same problem - did everything the same, keep getting rejected. Found [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027059) [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57284905) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57247675) with the same issue, no answer to be found...

Comment: Hi Stojke Still now problem continues. I have made an appeal.  and i have provided test  login details. after i have received mail from google play team that my appeal has been accepted. After that also  my app got rejected.Further mode i have made 4 -5 times i  appeal  to google play support team. One Note: you will be received mail from google play support team. From that you can mail to them. But after lot of struggle 20-25 days my app got approved. After that one week  i updated my app. Once again my app got rejected for same reason..Once again i'm going for appeal .

Comment: dont know exact solutions...

Answer (score 2):

Our app got approved today.In case if  your app got rejected because test login needed. you will received a mail from google play support team.In that you will have a text

*Please provide login credentials to the support team*

click the support team link and select test login needed and provide the details what they ask . after that you will receive mail from google developer support team.you will received no in the headline[similar to : [0-423523427159] ].

From that mail[kindly note you have to quote the no in the mail]... and then you can mail to  google support  about your problems.

*you can provide a screen shot + video. how you app works in that mail*

They will respond. May be it takes time. But they responding. Finally our app got approved.

Comment: After submitting credentials still getting same response please let me know how can i resolve it

Comment: Hi Madhav did you able to release the build or else forward your problem to karthikeyan1982@gmail.com .. I will try to solve your problems.

Comment: Yes i had submitted the build.
The reason was incorrect SHA-1 key.

Comment: I did not recieve any email from them , what to do now?

Comment: @LumbusterTick   I dont whats your problem. first you have to appeal  to Google Play.In that you will received mail from them. You have to continue with that mail. if u need any help mail to karthikeyan1982@gmail.com.. I can try to solve your problems.

Comment: @karthikkeyan it got solved thanks, turns out sometimes its a bug from play console that the warning keeps showing.

Comment: I want to share my experience, I got the credential warning about not providing login and password. 
I fixed it by adding the login and password in the console, That was Monday and then the error stay till Wednesday .
On Wednesday, the error went away with a message in console say
"A recent policy violation about your app has been addressed".